# Media Player with automatic File Scheduling

Tags: multimedia, mediaplayer

I'm looking for a media player/script possibility which allows me to implement the following possibility.

I've got a list of long video files(movies and such with play times on the order of the hour) which we'll call **A**, **B**, **C**... ; and a small list of videos from youtube and such(distracting clips, or small curiosities, usually not over 5 minutes) which we'll call the **alpha** group.

I want to schedule it on some kind of playlist which takes care of the details for me and replicates the following behaviour:

15h00 - Starts movie **A**;

16h30 - Movie **A** ends, starts a clip from **alpha**;

17h00 - Cuts whatever clip from **alpha** is currently running, starts movie **B**;

18h00 - Stops movie **B**, starts movie **C**;

And so on, and on...